# XSLT - split string using specific character

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml like this,

```
<doc>
    <para>A brief 23 spell* of hea#vy rain* forc^%ed an early+ lunch* 98@with nine</para>
</doc>
```

I need to break the text string from each * present in the  text..

SO expected output should be,

```
<doc>
    <para>A brief 23 spell</para>
    <para>of hea#vy rain</para>
    <para>forc^%ed an early+ lunch</para>
    <para>98@with nine</para>
</doc>
```

I've written following logic for that,

I have written following xslt for that,

```
<xsl:template match="para"> 
        <xsl:analyze-string select="text()" regex="[A-Za-z0-9_.]\*">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <para>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </para>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>
```

Can anyone suggest me how can i do this using xslt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Personal preference* I would go with the function **[tokenize()](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize)**:

> Summary: This function breaks the $input string into a sequence of strings, treating any substring that matches $pattern as a separator. The separators themselves are not returned.

```
<xsl:template match="para"> 
  <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,'\*')">
    <para>
      <xsl:sequence select="."/>
    </para>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

results in:

```
<para>A brief 23 spell</para>
<para> of hea#vy rain</para>
<para> forc^%ed an early+ lunch</para>
<para> 98@with nine</para>
```

To **strip** the leading and trailing whitespaces use:

```
<xsl:sequence select="normalize-space(.)"/>
```